# Angular 2 not working on IE despite using IE shims

Tags: angular

I have an issue with booting Angular 2 app - it doesn't start, and console prints 'Symbol is not defined'. I've addded the shims for IE (found solution on angular2 GitHub). Any ideas?

Comment: `es6-shim.min.js, 
system-polyfills.js, 
shims_for_IE.js, 
angular2-polyfills.js, 
system.src.js, 
Rx.js. 
angular2.dev.js, 
router.dev.js` i got these scripts on my `index.html`, i do not know what i am missing but angular doesn't running on IE :( , i was about to ask question, but i will just follow yours.